# How to tune hyperparameters of tf-agents and policies in Tensor Flow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I have set up a python environment that is wrapped in a tensor flow class to make it a tensor flow environment. Then I set up the learning as per the collab notebooks listed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/tree/master/docs/tutorials). Currently, I am using the dqn and REINFORCE agent.

The setup works well and the results are somewhat as expected. Now I want to go into the tuning of the hyperparameters like decaying epsilon greedy, weights etc.

I need some pointers on how to use the documentation on how to access these hyperparameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinforce doesn't not support epsilon greedy policy, I suggest switching to DQN agent or DDQN.

To pass a specified Q-Network you can use something like:

```
q_network=q_network.QNetwork(
        environment.time_step_spec().observation['observations'],
        environment.action_spec(),
        fc_layer_params=fc_layer_params)
```

and pass that to your agent on initialization. For a decaying epsilon-greedy policy you can define your own function `decaying_epsilon(train_step, *kwargs)` as you prefer. Then initialize your train_step tensor and pass it through `functools.partial` like this:

```
train_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step', dtype=tf.int64)
partial_decaying_eps = partial(decaying_epsilon, train_step *kwargs)
```

You can now pass `partial_decaying_eps`  to your agent and it will work as expected, updating with your `train_step` Tensor progressively. Be sure to pass this same `train_step` Tensor to your agent though.

Other HP can be modified easily, just look at the DQN documentation in its `__init__` function

Comment: yes I switched to dqn but I was also looking into the c51 implementation as it is supposedly better than standard dqn.